# What is an idiom that describes aiming for high achievement or success but not forgetting one's roots?

Tags: word-requests, phrase, synonyms, idioms

What is an idiom/phrase/saying that describes aiming for high achievement or success but not forgetting one's roots?

Something like 展翅高飞 and 饮水思源 combined

Comment: Why not use both together? Why does there have to be an idiom that combines both?

Comment: Do you mean something like a job promotion?

Comment: I'd say even for native speakers looking for the right idiom with a rough explanation could be hard. For now I can only think about 志存高远/志向远大 for aiming high and 不忘初衷/不忘初心/不忘本 for not forgetting one's roots.

Comment: What makes you believe such phrase exists? Did you encounter one? The context could be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

心存高远意守平常好听点，I don't know why I have to type at least 30 letters.

Comment: **心存高远，意守平常** is good, but maybe you could explain the components for OP.

Comment: The latter part is a little different form what OP wants.

Comment: in classical Chinese poetry, carefully balanced words sounds more skillful and comfortable, so 心 to 意 as a noun, 存to  守 as a verb, 高远 to 平常 as a  adj., verbal parallelism will show a kind of beauty of harmony.